# How to migrate a library using clarity to Angular 10?

Tags: vmware-clarity, angular10, tslib

I'm trying to bump Angular version in a mono-repo with several applications and libs.
One of those libs and one of those applications are using [Clarity framework](https://clarity.design/)

`ng update` fails because of clarity depending on `tslib` v1 when Angular 10 uses v2.

Is there any plan for clarity to upgrade to tslib V2?

Is any one using Angular 10 and clarity?

Even better, has any-one a lib depending on clarity and built with Angular 10?

Comment: We should have the official Clarity v4 release in the next few weeks. You can start using the release candidate if you install or upgrade with `@clr/angular@next` it is updated for Angular 10.

Comment: Thks @hippeelee. I could migrate to Angular 10 with @clr/angular 4.0.0-rc.0 but had to merge the code of the lib into application (couldn't get it working from a lib). As this lib is used by an app only, it is acceptable and didn't investigate much.